# Google+ share url: what parameters does it use?

Tags: google-plus, share

I want to make like on Stackoverflow. I do not whant `+1` button (it takes some time for loading and all page loading are little slower).
I've looked on source page and didn't found any info of it... How do they do it???

On facebook this is:

```
url  = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100';
url += '&p[title]='     + encodeURIComponent(title);
url += '&p[summary]='   + encodeURIComponent(text);
url += '&p[url]='       + encodeURIComponent(my_url);
url += '&p[images][0]=' + encodeURIComponent(pic);
```

Something like this must be for google+ share to, but i didn't found any helpful information during my search.

I know I can use such url: `https://plus.google.com/share?url=my_url`, but it's not enough - I also need share title, text and image, but what url GET parameters to use for this purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Plus share in a popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022416/google-plus-share-in-a-popup)

Answer (score 32):

The [share link](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink) supports two url paramaters: `url`, for the target url, and `hl`, for a language code.

The structured markup on the target url determines the title, description and image shared on Google+. For example, if you add schema.org markup or OpenGraph tags to the page that you're sharing it appears to pick it up just like it does for the +1 button.

In the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/) for the +Snippet it indicates that [schema.org markup](http://schema.org) is preferred. So if you add markup to your page that looks something like this:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="image-url"></img>
  <p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
</body>
```

you will see your title read from the `name` field and image from the aptly named `image` field.

Alternatively, you can add OpenGraph tags to the head of your page to specify the same fields like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:description" content="..."/>
```

Comment: What about for sharing an image?

Comment: You say "The structured markup on the target url determines the title, description...:" How do we construct url if we want to encode title and description?

Comment: i am wasting time to do this ..please help

Comment: @ZeKoU You can't specify them with URL parameters. You must use structured markup in the target page.

Comment: Works for me: https://plus.google.com/share?url=example.com&text=WorksForMe

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the following page about sharing interactive posts will be helpful:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive

I tested it already with the parameter "prefilled". This parameter allows you to define a prefilled text for the google+ share via get parameter:

https://plus.google.com/share?url=my_url&prefilltext=my_prefilled_text

So have a deeper look at the interactive posts page in order to find other possible get parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "url" and "prefilltext".

Answer (score 0):

You can use three parameters, like so:

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url={url}&text={desc}&hl={language_code}
```

Source: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls/blob/master/README.md#google