# Share TEXT to Google+?

Tags: share, google-plus

I'd like to allow my website (which allows users to post to the website itself, and, if the user enables it, Facebook) to be able to share a user's post to Google+. After reading through all I could find on stackoverflow/etc., it seems that the official G+ API doesn't allow you to post anything to a user's stream. That means that I'd have to use a share button/link/etc. The problem is, every share button/link I've found is for sharing _url_s...but I want to share text (and maybe an added URL if necessary)! If there's already a question answering this, sorry for reposting, but it must've gotten hidden beneath the ~ 5,000 questions that got returned for my search :D

Thanks,

Matthew

Comment: You can look at this answer for an alternative : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9459099/1671377

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Share API is intended for sharing pages, although you could share a page and have the Snippet data on that page contain the text that you want to share.

You may also want to look into the [History API](https://developers.google.com/+/history/), which is currently in developer preview, to see if it will meet your needs or to provide feedback to Google about what changes you might need.

Answer (score 0):

You may post a message like this..
whether G+ app is installed in your phone or not 
try it, this works for me

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    shareMediaButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
    shareMediaButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if(isGooglePlusInstalled())
                    {

                 PlusShare.Builder share = new PlusShare.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    share.setText("write your message here.....!");
                    //share.addStream(selectedImage);
                    share.setType("text/plain");

                    startActivityForResult(share.getIntent(), 0);

        }else{
             Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(MainActivity.this)
              .setType("text/plain")
              .setText("write your message here.....!")

              .getIntent();

          startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
        }
        }

        public boolean isGooglePlusInstalled()
{
    try
    {
        getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.android.apps.plus", 0 );
        return true;
    } 
    catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
    });
}
```