# iPhone App - Google plus share with pre-fill text

Tags: iphone, ios

I heard we can use this link to share on Google+
https://plus.google.com/share?url=YOUR_URL_HERE

How do we add a text to the 'share/post'? (like in Twitter, I can set the 'prefilled text' parameter) What is the URL parameter for it? Can someone help please?

Comment: I'm looking for the same feature, for Google+ and for Facebook

Comment: There seems to be at least no [documented](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink)  way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to tightly integrate your app with Google+ I would recommend using their SDK outlined here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/

The bit on sharing: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/#share_on_google

Create your share object:

```
GooglePlusShare *share =
    [[[GooglePlusShare alloc] initWithClientID:clientID] autorelease];
share.delegate = self; // optional
appDelegate.share = share; //optional
```

In your button's IBAction:

```
- (IBAction) didTapShare: (id)sender {
  // Add code here to retrieve the value of "share"
  // This could be self.share if this is a property of your ViewController
  // or ((MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).share

  [[[[share shareDialog]
      setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL_TO_SHARE"]]
          setPrefillText:@"YOUR TEXT HERE"] open];

  // Or, without a URL or prefill text:
  [[share shareDialog] open];
}
```

Google+ URL handler:

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
              openURL: (NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
           annotation: (id)annotation {
  // ...

  if ([self.share handleURL:url
          sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                 annotation:annotation]) {
    return YES;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: +1, I was so fixed on the URL that I didn't think of the SDK.

Comment: I did try their SDK, but I faced issues in integrating it (especially that OpenSource kit that they provide). I was struggling with this for few days, & I finally shifted to the simple way of using the URL !

Comment: Hi there, is there any way to publish post on google+ without share dialogue.. ?

Answer (score 1):

I've done a little research and came up with this:

- Google+, as opposed to e. g. [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button), does not allow any query parameters beside "url" for the URL and "hl" for the language code. [(Source: Documentation on developers.google.com)](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink-endpoint)
- Google+ uses meta-information supplied via [the schema.org microdata-format](http://www.schema.org/docs/gs.html) to decide which part of the content to use. [(Source: This German blog article on the same topic)](http://www.video-flash.de/index/google-plus-button-share-bild-text-festlegen/)

That said, you should be able to influence the content of the +1-share-thingy **if you control the shared page.** If not, there still seems no way to do this.

Also: This question seems to be an almost exact duplicate of [this question asked 2012-02-26 by Vitali Ponomar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456592/google-share-url-what-parameters-does-it-use)

Comment: It does not prefill the text of the post/comment. I have a page with several events, and I would like the user can select an event and share it on Google+ or Facebook (just the single event, not the whole page). It seems impossible on FB and G+, unless I create a page for each event. Nevertheless, thank you for the search you did.

Comment: @Baldrick You're welcome. Sorry, I confused FB and Twitter, corrected and added reference to documentation.