# How to add a customer title in Google+ share link

Tags: share, google-plus

As the facebook and twitter has a parameter for the url and for the title.

> https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[URL]&t=[TEXT]
>   http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=sharethiscom&text=[TEXT]&url=[URL]

what it the title parameter in google+ share link ?

> https://plus.google.com/share?url=[URL]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456592/google-share-url-what-parameters-does-it-use/36803298#36803298

Answer (score 3):

You can't supply it with the share link - that only accepts the URL to share and language as parameters. You can pre-fill the text if you use the share widget though: http://developers.google.com/+/web/share

The title of the page itself in the snippet is taken from the URL that is being shared. The title is either based on schema.org markup, open graph tags, or the title of the page. There's an example of setting that up on the snippet doc page: https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/