# iOS Google Plus sharing with custom GUI

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, google-plus

I have a question about [Google Plus iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/). Is there any way to share a photo and/or message without having to use `GPPShareBuilder`? I need to make a custom interface to do that and can't find any function or solution to make a simple sharing interface.

Ok. I've enabled Google Plus domains API in developers console. And trying to upload photo via [Media:insert](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/media/insert). Here is a code:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *body = @{ @"mediaURL" : photoURL.description };
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:body options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSURL *apiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/plusDomains/v1/people/me/media/cloud?access_token=%@", [self accessToken]]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:apiURL];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = jsonData;
[request addValue:@"image/JPG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSOperationQueue *queue= [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
{
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
}];
```

And all the time I getting next response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Google provides a [share](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink-endpoint) endpoint at `https://plus.google.com/share`.  This endpoint takes in two parameters: `url` for your image, and `hl` for your [language code](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#available-languages).

You can adjust the metadata that appears when posting your image to Google+ with OpenGraph tags (such as `og:title`) to the webpage hosting your image.

More about OpenGraph tags can be found in this question: [Google+ share url: what parameters does it use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456592/google-share-url-what-parameters-does-it-use)