# google share pop window not opening when click

Tags: javascript, web, google-plus, web-development-server

I am using a google share button but for some reason it does not open a pop window and instead opens it on fullscreen in same window.

```
<a class="google-plus" style="display:inline-block" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftarunkrishna.com%2F" title="Share on Google+">
  <span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Plus share in a popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022416/google-plus-share-in-a-popup)

Answer (score 0):

You only have an `<a>` link, this is how they work. From the [Google+ Share Link documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#share-link) you should include an `onclick` handler. The full documented example is:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
  '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img
  src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
```

Comment: sir thank you so so much... i'm still in learning phase.. i thought i'll never get it done. also sorry for lste reply